# Function body returns undefined compiles with a Promise signature

Tags: typescript

I expect this function to give a compiler error but it does not. Function body can return undefined, but type signature doesn't state that.

```
  async function chat(_: at.ChatLine): Promise<Array<tot.PlayStateAction>> {
    return lastMover?.chat(_);
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules", "**/.*/"]
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `strictNullChecks` in `tsconfig.json`.
Also either the type declaration of `lastMover` or the inferred type have to contain `null` and/or `undefined`. I can reproduce with this:

```
let lastMover: LastMover | undefined | null;
```

You will then get this exception:

> Type 'XXX[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'XXX[]'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'XXX[]'.

(where XXX would be `tot.PlayStateAction` in your case)

Side note: for some reason, even though the docs say `strict` should automatically enable `strictNullChecks`, it does *not* do so in the TS Playground ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=6&jsx=0&module=1&strict=true&ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEAykBcCyB7AbgUwE7QN4FgAoaaSATwDthpgALMBACgA8AuaCBLASwoHMAlO2gAFLCgC23CBgA8AQSxYwZWZx78AfJrxESJLBgQBXLBWgBtZgF0A3HugBfIs8JEQR6OE6pMWdvA+6NjQAD7QxhQAJhgAZrwYUWHQFMYgIPZuhORU0LGRwAjcKOZ0DIwA+uzqvILsYpLScorKqjVaOgTE0IYmZl6IvtgA-AB0ZUwVApmuQA) - uncheck `strictNullChecks` and you won't get the error).